# How to derive this upper bound for the entropy of a bounded random variable?

Tags: entropy, information-theory

> A continuous random variable $ Z $ has a density that is $0$ except over the interval $[−A, +A].$ Show that the differential entropy $h(Z)$ is upper bounded by $1+\log_2 A.$

I am stuck in this question of information theory.

Comment: What have you tried?  One approach is to prove this for a density function that attains at most two distinct values.  From there it's a short inductive step to simple functions and then an easy limiting argument proves it for all Lebesgue-integrable functions.

Comment: You need to add the self-study tag & expect hints but not complete answers.

Comment: I have tried newton lebinitz theorem but i keep on getting stuck there

Answer (score 2):

**Just apply [Jensen's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Measure-theoretic_and_probabilistic_form):** see the highlighted calculation at the end of this post.

The following provides details showing that this inequality is applicable and how to use it effectively.  (That's not completely obvious.)

---

By definition, the entropy of a distribution with cumulative probability function $F$ and density function $f = F^\prime$ is

$$H(f) = -\int \log(f(x)) f(x) \mathrm{d} x =  \int \log\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)  \mathrm{d}F(x).$$

This is well-defined because we may express it as an integral over the region where $f$ assigns nonzero probability density,

$$H(F) = \int_{x\mid f(x)\gt 0} \log\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)  \mathrm{d}F(x)$$

and on this region the denominator of $1/f(x)$ is never zero.  Define, then $g(x) = 1/f(x)$ over this region and otherwise set $g(x)=0.$  Evidently $g$ is measurable with respect to $F$ and

$$H(F) = \int \log(g(x)) \mathrm{d}F(x).$$

On the domain of positive numbers the logarithm is (strictly) *concave.*  Rigorously, concavity of a function $\phi$ means that at any $y_0\gt 0$ there is a *linear* function $y\to \alpha y + \beta$ for which

1. $\alpha y_0 + \beta = \phi(y_0)$ and
2. for all $y\gt 0,$ $\phi(y)\le \alpha y + \beta.$

Upon taking expectations, the latter inequality easily yields **Jensen's Inequality,** which says that for concave measurable functions $\phi$ and measurable functions $g,$

$$\int \phi(g(x))\mathrm{d}F(x) \le \phi\left(\int g(x)\mathrm{d}F(x)\right).$$

A standard theorem of differential Calculus asserts that when $\phi$ is twice-differentiable on an interval and its second derivative is everywhere negative on the interior of that interval, then $\phi$ is concave.  We can employ that result to verify that $\phi = \log$ is concave on $(0,\infty)$ simply by computing

$$\phi^{\prime\prime}(y) = -\frac{1}{y^2} \lt 0.$$

Therefore Jensen's Inequality applies and, restricting the integration to the interval $[-A,A]$ as in the question, gives

> $$\eqalign{
> H(F)&=\int \log(g(x))\mathrm{d}F(x) \le \log\left(\int g(x)\mathrm{d}F(x)\right)\\& =  \log\left(\int_{-A}^A\frac{1}{f(x)}f(x)\mathrm{d}x\right) \\&= \log(2A).}$$

When you use logarithms to another base (greater than $1$) you merely multiply the natural logarithm by a (positive) constant, which appears as a common factor on both sides of this inequality and therefore does not invalidate it.  Using logs base $2$ we find

$$H_2(F) \le \log_2(2A) = 1 + \log_2 A,$$

*QED.*

Finally, it may be worth remarking that equality can hold only when the function $x\to \log(1/f(x))$ is linear, which can happen only when $f$ is constant: that is, *the maximum-entropy distribution is the uniform distribution on $[-A,A].$*